# Multivariate Gaussian likelihood without matrix inversion

Tags: numpy, gaussian, normal-distribution

There are several tricks available for *sampling* from a multivariate Gaussian without matrix inversion--cholesky/LU decomposition among them.  Are there any tricks for calculating the likelihood of a multivariate Gaussian without doing the full matrix inversion?

I'm working in `python`, using `numpy` arrays.  `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal` is absurdly slow for the task, taking significantly longer than just doing the matrix inversion directly with `numpy.linalg.inv`.

So at this point I'm trying to understand what is best practice.